# Sort Dictionary By Date Value- Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, date, dictionary

So I need to be able to sort my dictionary from the value "date" (newest to oldest)

The way my dictionary is formatted is that there are multiple people with the values: date(creationdate), name and, email.
The array(peoples):

```
let bob =   ["name": "Bob", "date": Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1594756208.777499), "email": "bob@gmail.com"] as [String : Any]
let steve = ["name": "Steve", "date": Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1604756208.777499), "email": "steve@gmail.com"] as [String : Any]
let sammy = ["name": "Sammy", "date": Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1594756210.778510), "email": "sammy@gmail.com"] as [String : Any]
let peoples = [bob, steve, sammy}
```

With this array I tried to sort it like this:

```
let peoplesSorted = peoples.sorted(by: { 0$.date > 1$.date })
```

But it doesn't work and gives the error "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Date?' operands"

I also tried formatting the date into a string (yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss) but I couldn't figure out the code in the sorted() function.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message doesn't match the code. Apart from the typos you should get

> Ambiguous use of operator '>'

`Any` is the *don't care* type but the compiler must know the static type when applying operators.

And standard dictionaries don't support dot notation

```
let peoplesSorted = peoples.sorted(by: { ($0["date"] as! Date) > $1["date"] as! Date })
```

A better type is a custom struct which supports dot notation and strong types.

Comment: You beat me to it! I copied the OPs code to a test project to come up with a fix, and when I came back to post it, your answer was already here (voted)

Comment: This assumes the dictionary is well formed and that it will always contain a date key and its corresponding value is a Date otherwise it will crash. The safe approach would be  `peoples.sorted { $0["date"] as? Date ?? .distantFuture > $1["date"] as? Date ?? .distantFuture }`

Answer (score 1):

As vadian said, you have a dictionary of type `[String: Any]`. You can't use dot notation on dictionaries, and you also can't compare objects of type Any.

Taking vadian's suggestion, your code is cleaner if you refactor your dictionary as a struct:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let date: Date
    let email: String
}

let bob = Person(name: "Bob", date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1594756208.777499), email: "bob@gmail.com")
let steve = Person(name: "Steve", date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1604756208.777499), email: "steve@gmail.com")
let sammy = Person(name: "Sammy", date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1594756210.778510), email: "sammy@gmail.com" )


let peoples = [bob, steve, sammy]

let peoplesSorted = peoples.sorted {
    return $0.date > $1.date }

peoplesSorted.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

Comment: thanks, I just implemented it in my app along with the code to sort the array and it works like a charm.